# Series Form Entry

Tags: javascript, database, laravel

I want to insert data of employee into database with similar employee number, there are more than 7 forms in series, connected with NEXT button on each form (on click next, the next form will appear). How to insert all data into database on last form submission?

Comment: Did you refresh your page when you click on the next button? or you just hide some part of the form and show another part

Comment: on click next, the form values pass to controller and save to database and return view to the next form with id … the problem is tha at 3rd or 4th form ,when I close the window or refresh the page, the return id from the last form destroyed ..

Comment: half form with same id save to 2-3 tables ,and half tables have no values/id of the same series form .

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way is to store you data in [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session).

And on last submit, take from session and insert into your db.

Comment: yes this will be the best solotion but my question is how to route to the next form and then to the next form and travel with the previous forms sessions ?? and in the last form submission how can I get all the sessions in the last controller to save into the database ??

Comment: you could make temporary table, where you can save your data, and then in last route just check all data and copy from temp table to your real table

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel session for saving your temporary data `Session::set('title', $request->data)` and access it with laravel `Session::get('variableName');` you may refer to the [laravel documention for session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session)

Comment: this was the solution I was thinking, but storing the form data in one session than return view to the next form ,how can I pass the session also ?? and in the last form I save all the sessions in the database ?? I m stuck in between

Comment: do you also want to show previous saved data to user in next form?